# Get pgrep to determine length pid has been running

Tags: python, subprocess

I stubbed out some code to outline what Im trying to do. I just cant seem to get the syntax correct, can someone help?

```
def calc_execution():
    import subprocess
    #get the proc id of detectmotion; need help converting into subprocess
    detectmotion_file_pid = subprocess.call(pgrep -f "detectmotion.py")
    if detectmotion_file_pid:
        #determine how long pid has been running; note this seems to be incorrect
        len_run_time=subprocess.call(ps -o etime= -p detectmotion_file_pid)
        print len_run_time
```

My problem is getting the syntax for var `detectmotion_file_pid` and `len_run_time` to work correctly.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: @Attie please see updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` expects a string or array of strings as the `args` parameter - see the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).

You are providing:

`subprocess.call(pgrep -f "detectmotion.py")`, which is interpreted by python as:

- Take the value of the variable `pgrep`, and subtract `f`
- The string "detectmotion.py"

---

What you actually meant is:

```py
subprocess.call([ 'pgrep',  '-f',  'detectmotion.py'])
```

Each of the items in that array are used as an argument to the next process. `pgrep` identifies which binary you'd like to run (and shows up as arg 0 in the new process). `-f` and `detectmotion.py` are the next arguments.

For the next one (getting the runtime), you are doing the same thing again 
- a simple fix to the following.

```py
subprocess.call(['ps',  '-o',  'etime=',  '-p', detectmotion_file_pid ])
```

---

The last problem, is that you are expecting the return value of `subprocess.call()` to be the data you're after. In fact, `subprocess.call()` will:

> Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

If you want to catch the output of the command you just ran, then you'll need to use a "*pipe*", to bring the output of the command into your application, this is where things get messy, the docs say:

> **Note:** Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function as that can deadlock based on the child process output volume. You can use `Popen` with the `communicate()` method when you need pipes.

So...

```py
x = subprocess.Popen([ 'pgrep',  '-f',  'detectmotion.py'])
out, _ = x.communicate()

# out is currently a string, e.g: '26585\n'
print(out)

# convert it into an integer:
detectmotion_file_pid = int(out.rstrip())
```

You'll need to do something similar with the output of `ps -o etime= -p ...`, as this will return you the time in human-readable format.

```py
x = subprocess.Popen(['ps',  '-o',  'etime=',  '-p', str(detectmotion_file_pid) ])
out, _ = x.communicate()

# out is currently a string, e.g: '      12:53\n'
print(out)

# strip it
out = out.strip()

# now it's free of white-space, e.g: '12:53'
print(out)
```

---

At this point, you might ask yourself how to convert the seemingly `mm:ss` format into something more useful... Unfortunately the output of `ps` was designed for humans, and probably isn't terribly straightforward to parse like this.

You might prefer to look into [`/proc/[pid]/stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), which can tell you all sorts of info about a process: